# A table into a graph (beautifulsoup in python )

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

It possible (is there an easy way )to get a table out of a website and then translate it  into a graph not a table ?

Here is the code the code extracts a table into a table.

## import the library used to query a website

```
import urllib2

#specify the url
wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_state_and_union_territory_capitals_in_India"

#Query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
page = urllib2.urlopen(wiki)


#import the Beautiful soup functions to parse the data returned from the website
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


#Parse the html in the 'page' variable, and store it in Beautiful Soup format
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)



all_tables=soup.find_all('table')


right_table=soup.find('table', class_='wikitable sortable plainrowheaders')
right_table





#Generate lists
A=[]
B=[]
C=[]
D=[]
E=[]
F=[]
G=[]
for row in right_table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    states=row.findAll('th') #To store second column data
    if len(cells)==6: #Only extract table body not heading
        A.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
        B.append(states[0].find(text=True))
        C.append(cells[1].find(text=True))
        D.append(cells[2].find(text=True))
        E.append(cells[3].find(text=True))
        F.append(cells[4].find(text=True))
        G.append(cells[5].find(text=True))

#import pandas to convert list to data frame
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(A,columns=['Number'])
df['State/UT']=B
df['Admin_Capital']=C
df['Legislative_Capital']=D
df['Judiciary_Capital']=E
df['Year_Capital']=F
df['Former_Capital']=G
df
```

Comment: what graph ? Do you mean some plot ? pandas has functions to plot - check in documentation.

Comment: Yes a simple plot.

Comment: `df.plot()` ? `pandas` use `matplotlib` so you can find more in `matplotlib` documentation.

Comment: I am so beginner in this ( a week old if i can say). i am trying to figure out myself the solution. However any help with the code would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) and select second table by `[1]` (`read_html` return `list` of `DataFrames` from all tables in webpage) with [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_state_and_union_territory_capitals_in_India', header=0, index_col=0)[1]
print (df)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#there are 2 values of year, if need first add [0] if secind add [1] after split()
df.loc[2, 'Year capital was established'] = df.loc[2, 'Year capital was established'].split()[0]
df.loc[21, 'Year capital was established'] = df.loc[21, 'Year capital was established'].split()[0]
#convert to number years
df['Year capital was established'] = df['Year capital was established'].astype(int)
df.plot(x='Judiciary capitals', y='Year capital was established')
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: That is a perfect answer. Just one thing to ask df.loc[2, and df.loc[21  How did you get these numbers ?

Comment: Good question. The easier is check table in html page where are in one cell multiple years. More general solution is use function to_numeric with errors='coerce' - it return Nan for not numeric valus and then can check indeces by isnull function. Something like df[pd.to_numeric(df['Year capital was established'], errors='coerce').isnull()].index

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas' [`readhtml`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) function, you just need a table with some good numeric data (see the one in the snippet below). Then use the `plot` function and you have a good starting point.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_and_territories_by_area', header=0, index_col=0, skiprows=1)[1]
df.plot(x='sq mi', y='sq mi.2', kind='scatter')
plt.xlabel('Total area [sq mi]')
plt.ylabel('Water [sq mi]')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thats is also a very clear example for me and i guess for every new beginner thanks Mr Maximilian Peters (y) .